# PowerShell : How can I include single quotations in Argument?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, arguments

I'd like to pass the argument include '' single quotations for PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd as follows.

Batch:

```
set table_name=XXXX
set extract_condition=start_dt='2016-10-01'
%PS_EXE%  -ExecutionPolicy ByPass  %PS_DIR%\Export_S3.ps1 -StrTableName %table_name% -StrCondition %extract_condition%
```

PowerShell:

```
$StrQry="select * from " + $StrTableName + " where " + $StrCondition + ";"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $StrQry
```

It returns Operand Error, "date is not compatible with int", might be due to single quotation is not sent to PowerShell.
(It can work unless $StrCondition has no sinble quotation)

In actual case, we'd like to handle many tables with different extract conditions, so those variables should be read respectivelly from the list file in batch for loop.

I'd be appreciated if you would give us any advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass *literal* arguments to a script, use `-File` rather than the (implied) `-Command` parameter; also, double-quote them, to be safe:

```
%PS_EXE% -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "%PS_DIR%\Export_S3.ps1" -StrTableName "%table_name%" -StrCondition "%extract_condition%"
```

<sup>As an aside: In PowerShell *Core*, `-File` is now the default.</sup>

---

If you use `-Command` (possibly by default in Windows PowerShell), the arguments passed are interpreted by PowerShell as they would be from within PowerShell itself, and a token such as `start_dt='2016-10-01'`, i.e., one *without outer quoting*, simply has the embedded single quotes *stripped*, which you can verify from within PowerShell itself:

```
PS> Write-Output start_dt='2016-10-01'
start_dt=2016-10-01  # !! single quotes were STRIPPED.
```

While enclosing the token as whole in `"..."` would have helped in this case, it is generally preferable to use `-File` if your intent is to pass *literal* values to a script - i.e., values that shouldn't be interpreted by PowerShell on receipt.